# writing unit tests for 3rd party applications

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, third-party-libraries

Does anyone have any comments on how to write unit tests for 3rd party applications like kamailio...that allow you to write "configuration scripts"?
https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/4.0.x/core/cfg#the_configuration_file
I'm looking for more an approach vs. specifics.

In this particular case, these configuration files are written in a proprietary script format that kamailio understands.
Kamailio itself provides a compile option will test syntax of these files... but not much more.

We also have lua code that these cfg files call.  I think its going to be a little easier to write unit tests for these methods in the lua files... except that some of the functions are expecting data from the cfg.
My idea is to capture / dump this data ... and for the unit tests, seed the tests with data that looks like what kamailio would send via these cfgs and then test from there.

Comment: I think that [How to test when arranging the data is too cumbersome?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/264563) may be related to your question, but what is it that you want your tests to verify? Your Lua code, or the config scripts?

Comment: both.  so much of the SIP solution we've generated is in configuration scripts that we've written... that also call external lua files

Comment: Well, I guess what you are asking for is probably too broad for the Q&A format of this site. There is probably no "easy" way to solve this, you need to try out different approaches, get the details right, need a lot of diligence and reasearch effort, and see how it comes out. And there is probably no general solution for "applications like kamailio" - there might be a specific solution for kamailio, so this is a tool specific question, which makes it off-topic for "Programmers".

Comment: How do you unit test 3rd party applications?  The short answer is - you don't.  You can set up some automated integration tests, but that's about it.